# Reuse session from previous service task

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I’m developing a **custom connector** via ssh using host, user, password, port and command as input parameters, in order to establish a connection, and as output parameter, a parameter to retrieve the response (command response).
At this point, I could make the connection and retrieve the response, the problem is that I would like to **reuse the session created**, if there is another service task using the same connector in the bpmn process.
But in Camunda Modeler, I could only retrieve text (not objects).

In the image below I describe the flow, as well as the parameters I’m using.

[image]